# @media query overwritten by javascript DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, css, dom, media-queries

I have a @media query hiding/showing a DOM element by setting "display:none;" based on screen orientation. The following CSS works fine.

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  #header-container {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

But after hiding and showing the same element in my javascript seems to break the media query. For example

```
//JS

this.element.find('#header-container').css(display: "none");

//And later..

this.element.find('#header-container').fadeIn(500);
```

The element is no longer hidden/shown based on orientation

My guess is that the .fadeIn() method sets a new value to the display property, and the only way I have found getting around this is to put !important in the media query like so:

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  #header-container {
    display: none !important; 
  }
}
```

Is using !important the only way to make the media queries persistent even after DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation/CSS with jQuery usually modifies the `style` attribute with the respective styles. So if it writes some `display` property in there that will override the `CSS` in stylesheet.

```
<div id="header-container" style="display:block;opacity:1"></div>

@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  #header-container {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

It should be some situation like above, so `display` will be `block` instead of `none`. Inline style has the highest precedence (only exception being use of [important)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules).  **Also note that media-query [doesn't have any extra precedence](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/), they work just like IF statements.**

Meanwhile, you can override inline styles with `[important][1]` which you have already done as in:

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  #header-container {
    display: none !important; 
  }
}
```

Apparently, there is no *other* way to override inline `CSS` from within stylesheet. If you think about that, there can't be a reference to a DOM Node more **specific** than writing the `CSS` directly on the DOM Node itself in its `style` attribute.

In your scenario, you could reset the `style` of the element after doing `jQuery` animations, so reset the `style` after `fadeIn` is complete:

```
this.element.find('#header-container').fadeIn(500, function(){
    $(this).attr('style', '');
});
```

> To briefly list the different cases in precedence order:
>
> 1. Style declared in "style attribute" with !important keyword.
> 2. Style declared in "stylesheet" with !important attribute.
> 3. Normal style declared in style attribute (without !important attribute).
> 4. Normal Style in style sheet.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! The "reset" solution does work, however the element is briefly visible before the reset is executed, so perhaps the "!important" declaration in the @media query is actually justified in this case:/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is that the jQuery fadeIn method adds inline CSS so this will overwrite what is in the stylesheet. You could have some JS that fades it out again / hides it. I would not recommend putting display: none !important on it because then you will not be able to use JS to control the visibility. I'm assuming that in some state you want this element to be shown.

Any of the below should work.

```
//JS

this.element.find('#header-container').css(display: "none");

//And later..

this.element.find('#header-container').fadeIn(500);

// Later again.

this.element.find('#header-container').fadeOut(500);
this.element.find('#header-container').hide();
```

If you post more code I could give you a more detailed answer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your javascript in an if statement like this, but doesn't work too well with responsive design. Just another way it could be done.

```
if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight){
    some javascript for landscape position
}
else{
    some javascript for portrait position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

redneck style removal :), get the fade in effects , at success fading -> remove the style (generated by fade-in) witch is overriding media query.

```
this.element.find('#header-container').fadeIn(500, function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```